# Retrofit Error Protocol not found

Tags: android, mysql, retrofit

I am pretty new to android..

What I am trying to do is insert some data to MySQL server which is hosted in localhost.

I am trying to insert 3 fields which is Date, Time, and Location using Retrofit.

I have created an Interface for Retrovit and below are the code I have

```
public interface RegisterAPI {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/lantas_minut/insert.php")
public void insertLokasi(
        @Field("tanggal") String tanggal,
        @Field("waktu") String waktu,
        @Field("lokasi") String lokasi,
        Callback<Response> callback);
}
```

I have also created the method for insert the data which is shown below

```
private void insertLokasi(){
    //Here we will handle the http request to insert user to mysql db
    //Creating a RestAdapter
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL) //Setting the Root URL
            .build(); //Finally building the adapter

    //Creating object for our interface
    RegisterAPI api = adapter.create(RegisterAPI.class);

    //Defining the method insertuser of our interface
    api.insertLokasi(

            //Passing the values by getting it from editTexts
            textViewTanggal.getText().toString(),
            textViewWaktu.getText().toString(),
            editTextLokasi.getText().toString(),

            //Creating an anonymous callback
            new Callback<Response>() {

                @Override
                public void success(Response result, Response response) {
                    //On success we will read the server's output using bufferedreader
                    //Creating a bufferedreader object
                    BufferedReader reader = null;

                    //An string to store output from the server
                    String output = "";

                    try {
                        //Initializing buffered reader
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));

                        //Reading the output in the string
                        output = reader.readLine();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //Displaying the output as a toast
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    //If any error occured displaying the error as toast
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                }
    );


}
```

I have successfully installed it on my device and running smoothly, however, when I try to click the button to insert the data it shows "protocol not found:192.168.1.8/lantas_minut/insert.php"

The code below is my insert.php script.

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    //Getting post data
    $tanggal = $_POST['tanggal'];
    $waktu = $_POST['waktu'];
    $lokasi = $_POST['lokasi'];

    //Checking if the received values are blank
    if($tanggal=='' || $waktu=='' || $lokasi=='') {
        //Show message to fill all values
        echo 'please fill all values';
    }else{
        //if the values are not blank than connect to database

        //sql query to insert into database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_macet (tanggal,waktu,lokasi) VALUES ('$tanggal','waktu','lokasi')";
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
            echo 'Data berhasil disimpan';
        }else{
            echo 'Terjadi kesalahan';
        }
        }
    //mysqli_close('$con');
    }else{
    echo 'Error';
}
?>
```

Please somebody help me.. I am stuck on this situation..

Any feedback would be very appreciated..

Thank you..

Comment: You have to put http://

Comment: thank you anyway for your help... It works.. I really appreciated..